# Linker errors when compiling libgit2 static Library

Tags: c++, libgit2

I've successfully built a cross-platform static library for OSX with the following steps:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF "-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64;i386" ..
cmake --build .
```

I have also mostly-successfully linked that library into my own project, but now am getting a slew of linker errors in XCode 5.1.1 about missing symbols:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_SSLClose", referenced from:
  _stransport_close in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLCopyPeerTrust", referenced from:
  _stransport_connect in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
  _stransport_certificate in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLCreateContext", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLHandshake", referenced from:
  _stransport_connect in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLRead", referenced from:
  _stransport_read in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLSetConnection", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLSetIOFuncs", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLSetPeerDomainName", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLSetProtocolVersionMax", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLSetProtocolVersionMin", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLSetSessionOption", referenced from:
  _git_stransport_stream_new in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SSLWrite", referenced from:
  _stransport_write in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
  _stransport_certificate in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SecCopyErrorMessageString", referenced from:
  _stransport_error in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
  _stransport_connect in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
"  _SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex", referenced from:
  _stransport_certificate in libVAST.a(stransport_stream.c.o)
...
...
```

and on and on.

I imagine there's an extra step or dependency in there somewhere I'm missing, and I got a few hints that it's not entirely without precedent given this git-hub thread on rust, (https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2295) but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is an old version of OSX and libgit2. Some versions of libgit2 assume that the Security framework on OSX/macOS always provides SecureTransport (the library providing the cryptographic/TLS symbols you are missing).

This is not the case for the older opearating systems. This was fixed in late 2015 and the fix is included in the v0.24 release series as well in v0.23.2.